# Function Property PivotTable Class

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am at a loss as to what the problem is surrounding this error. I have modeled this snippet of code off of other reports I have done, where there is no error. But this one is unable to get the Function Property of the PivotFields class. I get this error whether I do xlSum or XlCount

```
    Function exportXl(strSD As String, strED As String) As String
Dim fname As String, fso As Object, xlApp As Object, xlBook As Object, xlSheet As Object, xlObj As Object, xlPT As Object, xlPC As Object, c As Object
fname = CurrentProject.Path & "\SupervisorEscalationsReport_" & Replace(strED, "/", "-") & ".xlsx"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FileExists(fname) Then Kill fname

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "t_SiebCnt", fname

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlBook = xlApp.workbooks.Open(fname)
Set xlSheet = xlBook.sheets(1)

With xlSheet
    .Name = "t_SiebCnt"
    Set xlObj = .ListObjects.Add(1, .Range("$A$1:" & .Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(11).Address), , 1)
    xlObj.Name = "Src_Table"
    xlObj.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium16"
End With

Set xlPC = xlBook.PivotCaches.Create(1, "Src_Table", 5)
Set xlSheet = xlBook.sheets.Add
xlSheet.Name = "Report"

xlApp.ScreenUpdating = False

Set xlPT = xlPC.CreatePivotTable(xlSheet.Range("A3"), "Supervisor Escalation Rollup Report")

With xlPT

    With .PivotFields("AssignedToSalesID")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        '.Position = 1
        .Caption = "Sales ID"
    End With

    With .PivotFields("Location")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        '.Position = 1
        .Caption = "Site"
    End With

     With .PivotFields("FullName")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        '.Position = 1
        .Caption = "Supervisor Name"
    End With

      With .PivotFields("Generated_On")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
       ' .Position = 2
        .Caption = "Day Generated"
    End With

      With .PivotFields("Closed_On")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
       ' .Position = 2
        .Caption = "Day Closed"
    End With

    With .PivotFields("DaysOpen")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
       ' .Position = 2
        .Caption = "Days Open"
    End With

   With .PivotFields("Status")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
       ' .Position = 2
        .Caption = "Status"
    End With




   With .PivotFields("CountActivityUID")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlCount
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
        .Caption = "Count of Status"
    End With


.PivotFields("Day Generated").ShowDetail = False



    .TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium2"
    .RowAxisLayout 1
    .InGridDropZones = True
    .DisplayErrorString = True
End With
```

[image]

Above is the full code along with a sample image of the table I am creating my pivot table from.

Comment: I'm assuming it's not the issue, but are you working with OLAP data? See the Remarks in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.function).

Comment: No @BigBen I am not. It is just coming from a database in Hadoop

Comment: And you can create the field manually?

Comment: Yeah, I can create it manually with no problem.

Comment: What code does the macro recorder produce when you create it manually?

Comment: Can you provide a data sample to go with enough code to reproduce? An image to show layout as well. Reduce to enough to repro problem.

Comment: for the sake of asking... is "countactivityuid" spelled correctly and do you have `on error resume next` anywhere in your code?

Comment: The macro recorder says the Add a Data Field. But I am not sure why I would need to since it is already on my table. Also, @Cyril, CountActivityUID is spelled correctly.